# how to check if x-staticmap-api-warning response header exists?

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, google-maps-static-api

I'm working on a project for school using the google static map api. There is a table with a list of locations. When you click on a location it brings up a modal window with the google map. If the api cannot find the location it just shows a map of water with an error. I noticed in the developer console under network there is a response header under the staticmap call titled x-staticmap-api-warning which contains the error.

Is there a way in javascript that can check if this response header exists so I can display a "Location unknown" message instead?